# Libgdx chainshape position

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to make a game where the player ( the circle ) has to collect some stars. The stars will be at different positions and in order to get the stars the player must draw ramps in order to reach the stars. Picture below.

http://3w-bg.org/game/pic.PNG

The red line is where the user has drawn on the screen.

Ok so i capture the coordinates when the user touches and drags on the screen and then i use this coordinates to create a ChainShape for the line. The problem is that the line is drawn nowhere near the touched area. Picture below.

http://3w-bg.org/game/pic2.PNG

The world and the screen positions are not the same to my understanding. So how can i draw the chainshape line exactly where the user has touched. Tried camera.project/unproject but that didn't help.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code, and please show us what have you tried, where's the problem etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when using Box2D you should have some kind of pixel-to-meter ratio defined. This is done in order to keep the coordinates in your physics world smaller to keep numeric stability.

When using a `Camera` and a constant `PIXEL_TO_METER` to convert the values, you can convert your coordinates like this:

```
public static Vector2 screenToPhysics(Camera camera, Vector2 screenPos) {
    Vector3 worldPos = camera.unproject(new Vector3(screenPos.x, screenPos.y, 0));
    return new Vector2(worldPos.x, worldPos.y).scl(1f / PIXEL_TO_METER);
}

public static Vector2 physicsToScreen(Camera camera, Vector2 physicsPos) {
    Vector3 worldPos = new Vector3(physicsPos.x, physicsPos.y, 0).scl(PIXEL_TO_METER);
    Vector3 screenPos = camera.project(worldPos);
    return new Vector2(screenPos.x, screenPos.y);
}
```

Comment: I've used similar code to achieve this, but i'd wonder about the performance. If you create a new Vector3 and new Vector2 on each call. Its funny when running on the PC i got great performance because of the JIT. However when I ran it on an older phone it kept resulting in garbage collections which had a noticeable performance loss. In the end I made a non-thread safe class with a local vairable

Comment: @joey.enfield My answer was just supposed to show the principle. I didn't care about the performance.